# Update Attributes/Create New data using a modal for another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, controller, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a data using a bootstrap modal. Here is what I have.

I have a UsersController which has a show action. On the show page there is a button to show a modal that I want to create a new UserResult. The UserResultsController has a new and a create method, however because I create the modal on the show page, I can't pass data to the modal from the UserResultsController.

```
def new
  @some_data = params[:some_data] # coming from users#show
  @user_result = current_user.user_results.new
end
```

Since this action never gets called when I show the modal, I can't pass @some_data in which is why I can't create a valid form for the UserResult model. How can make sure this new gets called when the "Add Result" button is called from the users#show action?

By the way the add result button is as follows:

```
link_to 'Add Result', new_user_result_path(some_data: :some_data), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-mini', data: { toggle: 'modal', target: '#add-result-modal' }, remote: true
```

Quick Edit: When I try to launch the show page without having a @user_result in the users#show action I get the following error. `undefined method model_name for NilClass:Class`

Answer (score 0):

if you mean your users_controller doesn't have access to UserResults_Controller then you must define the relation between them.
in you User model you must add:

```
has_many :UserResults
```

and in you UserResults_Controller add:

```
belongs_to :User
```

I hope this is what you mean.